# MS Query Analyzer / Management Studio replacement?

Tags: sql-server, database

I've been using SQL Server since version 6.5 and I've always been a bit amazed at the fact that the tools seem to be targeted to DBAs rather than developers. I liked the simplicity and speed of the Query Analyzer for example, but hated the built-in editor, which was really no better than a syntax coloring-capable Notepad. Now that we have Management Studio the *management* part seems a bit better but from a developer standpoint the tools is even worse. Visual Studio's excellent text editor... without a way to customize keyboard bindings!? Don't get me started on how unusable is the tree-based management hierarchy. Why can't I re-root the tree on a list of stored procs for example the way the Enterprise Manager used to allow? Now I have a treeview that needs to be scrolled horizontally, which makes it eminently useless.

The SQL server support in Visual Studio is fantastic for working with stored procedures and functions, but it's terrible as a general ad hoc data query tool.

I've tried various tools over the years but invariably they seem to focus on the management side and shortchange the developer in me. I just want something with basic admin capabilities, good keyboard support and requisite DDL functionality (ideally something like the Query Analyzer). At this point I'm seriously thinking of using vim+sqlcmd and a console... I'm that desperate :)

Those of you who work day in and day out with SQL Server and Visual Studio... do you find the tools to be adequate? Have you ever wished they were better and if you *have* found something better, could you share please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself stick to using the SSMS as a database dev - enhanced with SQL Prompt and SQL Search, it's actually quite good in my opinion.

Alternatives are plentiful - I've never really managed to get hooked on any of them - but you might find one that suits your style and needs!

- [MiniSQL Query](http://minisqlquery.codeplex.com/)
- [Apex SQL Edit](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_edit.asp)
- [EMS SQL Server Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mssql/manager)
- [TOAD for SQL Server](http://www.toadsoft.com/toadsqlserver/toad_sqlserver.htm)

And if you're searching for a particular item, or an SSMS add-in, this seems to be the ultimate list of SQL Server tools - not sure how current and up to date this is, the post is from November 2007 - but it might be helpful nonetheless:

- [Free SQL Server tools that might make your life easier](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/11/20/Free-SQL-Server-tools-that-might-make-your-life-a.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A coworker of mine swears by the SQuirreL SQL Client at http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net.  It is open source, works with many different types of databases, and looks like it has good features.  It looks like something you might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll give it a look tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

For ad-hoc queries, have you tried [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)?  It is .NET oriented, so it may not work for you.

I work day-in and day-out with both SQL Server Management Studio  (SSMS) and Visual Studio.  However, we usually use SQL statements to maintain schema instead of a UI tool.  Some advantages of using queries to maintain schema is being able to check the queries into source control and reusability in install programs.  So if you find any random SQL execution tool, you should be able to use it to maintain schema.

We also use queries to maintain our SQL Server Agent jobs.

I also use SSMS Activity Monitor daily.  It's nice, though I wish it could export and load its data.

Comment: I looked at LINQPad and it's interesting but it places too much emphasis on the LINQ thing. I just want a lightweight query tool with a good text editor component.

Answer (score 1):

[SQuirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net) is good

I use SSMS exclusively as a developer DBA though.

I recall some bloggers around the time of SQL Server 2005 release complained there wasn't enough for *DBAs* in SSMS...